# Display table data to vuetify select tag

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

just want help am using laravel as backend and vue js. vuetify for the front end.

Basically I want to display a data from my table to my v-select tag in vuetify here is my snippet code so far

```
locations_table 
id  name
1   box 1
2   box 2
3   box 3
```

here is my v-select tag

```
<v-col cols="12" sm="12" md="6">
    <v-select :items="locations" label="Location" v-model="item.location"></v-select>
</v-col>
```

and here is my code for script tag

```
locations: [
          { text: 'Name', align: 'start', value: 'name', },
        ],
```

and finally the output.
[image]

hope someone can help

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to v-select docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props)

**items**

> Can be an array of objects or array of strings. When using objects,
> will look for a text, value and disabled keys. This can be changed
> using the item-text, item-value and item-disabled props. Objects that
> have a header or divider property are considered special cases and
> generate a list header or divider; these items are not selectable.

If you can't change schema of objects use `item-text` `item-value` props

```
<v-col cols="12" sm="12" md="6">
    <v-select :items="locations"
           :item-text="pr => pr.name"
           :item-value="pr => pr.id"
           label="Location"
           v-model="item.location"></v-select>
</v-col>
```